# Plotting smoothed hazard ratio intervals for interaction terms

Tags: r, survival, interaction, smoothing

I don't know if it is possible.

I am following Terry Therneau's  [*Spline terms in a Cox model*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/splines.pdf) vignette available for `survival` package.

In Section 3, Splines in an interaction, he shows how to visualise the interaction between sex and age where age is included in the model using splines.

The command he uses are

```
library(survival)
library(splines)
nfit3 <- coxph(Surv(futime, death) ~ sex * ns(age, df=3), flchain)
pdata <- expand.grid(age= 50:99, sex=c("F", "M"))
ypred <- predict(nfit3, newdata=pdata, se=TRUE)
yy <- ypred$fit + outer(ypred$se, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
matplot(50:99, exp(matrix(yy, ncol=6)), type='l', lty=c(1,1,2,2,2,2),
        lwd=2, col=1:2, log='y',
        xlab="Age", ylab="Relative risk")
legend(55, 20, c("Female", "Male"), lty=1, lwd=2, col=1:2, bty='n')
abline(h=1)
```

Which end up with the with plot with the relative risk with respect average population [image]

I would like to have a plot where x axis shows *age* and y axis shows the *effect of being male of certain age with respect being a female of the same age*. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4):

I've just seen this question made by myself one year ago that I managed to deal with recently, I hope correctly. I put the script in case that it can be of help to another person and to see if somebody detects something wrong.

Following the example given in the question we can calculate the hazard ratio and their 95% interval with

```
age.spline = ns(flchain$age, df=3)

X.p = cbind(pdata$sex == 'M',
            predict(age.spline, pdata$age),
            predict(age.spline, pdata$age) * (pdata$sex == 'M'))

lHR = apply(matrix(rowSums( t(t(X.p) * coef(nfit3)) ), ncol = 2), 1, diff)
AGE.pred = (X.p[X.p[,1]==1,] - X.p[X.p[,1]==0,])
s2.age = apply(AGE.pred, 1, function(x){
  t(x) %*% vcov(nfit3) %*% x
})

plot(50:99, exp(lHR), type = 'l', ylab = 'Hazard ratio', xlab = 'Age', lwd=2)
points(50:99, exp(lHR - 1.96 * sqrt(s2.age)), type= 'l', lty = 2, lwd=2)
points(50:99, exp(lHR + 1.96 * sqrt(s2.age)), type= 'l', lty = 2, lwd=2)
abline(h=1)
```

which ens up with the following plot
[image]

---

**Extended after a question appeared in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/issue_with_R_code_for_additive_Cox_model).**

The approach can be further generalized to other packages. For example the package `mgcv`, which allows the user to fit an additive cox model with certain smooth terms (p.e. thin plate regression splines).

```r
library(mgcv)
nfittp = gam(futime~sex+s(age,by=sex,bs='tp'), 
             data=flchain, weights = death, 
             family = 'cox.ph', method = 'REML')

df.male  = expand.grid(sex = 'M', age = 50:99)
df.female = expand.grid(sex = 'F', age = 50:99)

y0.male_ = predict(nfittp,newdata=df.male,type="lpmatrix")
y0.female_ = predict(nfittp,newdata=df.female,type="lpmatrix")

y0.male = predict(nfittp,newdata=df.male,type="link", se.fit=TRUE)
y0.female = predict(nfittp,newdata=df.female,type="link", se.fit=TRUE)

dplot = data.frame(
  age = 50:99,
  b.male = y0.male$fit - y0.female$fit,
  s.male = sapply(1:length(50:99), function(i){
    l = matrix(y0.male_[i,] - y0.female_[i,])
    t(l) %*% vcov(nfittp) %*% l
  })
)


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(50:99, exp(y0.female$fit), type='l', log='y', lwd=2, xlab="Age", ylab="Relative risk", ylim=c(0.1,50))
points(50:99, exp(y0.female$fit + 1.96 * y0.female$se.fit), type='l', col=1, lwd=2, lty=2)
points(50:99, exp(y0.female$fit - 1.96 * y0.female$se.fit), type='l', col=1, lwd=2, lty=2)
points(50:99, exp(y0.male$fit), type='l', col='red', lwd=2)
points(50:99, exp(y0.male$fit + 1.96 * y0.male$se.fit), type='l', col=2, lwd=2, lty=2)
points(50:99, exp(y0.male$fit - 1.96 * y0.male$se.fit), type='l', col=2, lwd=2, lty=2)
legend(50, 40, c("Female", "Male"), lty=1, lwd=2, col=1:2, bty='n')
abline(h=1)

plot(50:99, exp(dplot$b.male), type = 'l', ylab = 'Hazard ratio', xlab = 'Age', lwd=2, ylim = c(0.8,2))
points(50:99, exp(dplot$b.male - 1.96 * sqrt(dplot$s.male)), type= 'l', lty = 2, lwd=2)
points(50:99, exp(dplot$b.male + 1.96 * sqrt(dplot$s.male)), type= 'l', lty = 2, lwd=2)
abline(h=1)
```

[image]

Comment: This is done easily with the R `rms` package `cph` and `contrast.rms` functions.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Wow it is really a surprising plot. But i am interested that the confidence interval in the second plot is equal to the real CI of hazard ratio in  univariate K-M analysis for age. Besides, is there a method could  i include several other variates in the model to get a multi variate COX analysis and the corresponding HR and CI. I am looking forward to the answer,Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please do not use the "Your Answer" field to ask new or
follow-up questions. Instead, click the blue 
[ASK QUESTION](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) link at the top
of the page & ask there. If you want to address the author of an answer, you will
need 50 reputation first to leave comments. Since you're new here, you may want
to take our [tour], which has information for new users.